# ListView.builder inside Stack returns Null Check error used on a null value

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I'm trying to create a list of tasks inside a circle, when the user taps on it, the list is showed. The problem is that the list of tasks is dynamic, I need to use a `ListView.builder` but it keeps giving out errors.
I've checked the following:

- If instead of a `.builder`, I use a `ListView`, it works fine.
- The `itemCount` and `shrinkWrap` have noting to do with it.

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderViewport#1d072 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1785
> pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was ListView
> lib/TaskBubble.dart:43
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library
> ═════════════════════════════════ Null check operator used on a null
> value
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by Flutter framework
> ═════════════════════════════════ Bad state: Future already completed
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

And here is the code

```
class _TaskBubbleState extends State<TaskBubble> {
  double yOffset = 175.0;
  double xOffset = 50.0;

  bool hide = true;

  List<Task> tasks = [
    new Task(name: "Laundry", done: false),
    new Task(name: "hide", done: false)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: yOffset,
      left: xOffset,
      child: Draggable<Widget>(
        onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
          setState(() {
            yOffset = offset.dy;
            xOffset = offset.dx;
          });
        },
        feedback: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Opacity(
          opacity: 0.1,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: tasks.length,
              shrinkWrap: true ,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(tasks[index].name),
              ),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  hide = !hide;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you prefer to use Positioned and Stack?

Comment: @Akif I use`Positioned` to set the position when the user drags the object, and `Stack` because I need the`List` to go together with the `FloatingActionButton`. Would you have done something else? I'm quite new to Flutter and I appreciate any feedback ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this issue with ListView not necessarily with .builder. The solution was to add a scrollController. on your builder, add:

```
   ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,//new line
          itemCount: tasks.length,
          shrinkWrap: true ,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text(tasks[index].name),
          ),
```

inistantiate your scroller:

```
ScrollController _controller;
```

initilize the controller:

```
@override
 void initState() {
 _controller = ScrollController();
 _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);//the listener for up and down. 
 super.initState();
}
```

add the listener.

```
_scrollListener() {
  if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
     !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
   setState(() {//you can do anything here
   });
 }
 if (_controller.offset <= _controller.position.minScrollExtent &&
    !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
   setState(() {//you can do anything here
    });
  }
}
```

while this solved the error: *null check operator used on a null value the relevant error-causing widget was listview*, and *Bad state: Stream has already been listened to*, I do not have streams or anything. I did not experience this in other ListView widgets. Not sure if this is with the new Flutter 1.22.2?? My case was only when getting values into a dropdown. Otherwise, same code works in another setting.

Comment: This solved the problem, even if I don't understand why. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

wrap your ListView.builder with Container provide a height to it.

like for your code-

```
child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tasks.length,
                shrinkWrap: true ,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(tasks[index].name),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  hide = !hide;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `key` property in your `ListTile(key: Key("Your Key"))`

Answer (score -2):

you can just wrap `ListView` with an `Expanded` widget

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tasks.length,
        shrinkWrap: true ,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(tasks[index].name),
        ),
      ),
    ),
)
```